# php oop начало движка

Tags: php, ооп

Привет друзья
я начинающий в сфере php
и хочу писать свой движок на php oop
так вот 
для начала не могу найти материал, вернее не могу сформировать вопрос чтобы найти ответ. Суть такова:

мне надо сделать определенный список страниц на которые пользователь может зайти

и сразу же чпу

и по поводу шаблонизатора: там как я понял загружается шаблон потом в него с другого файла загружаются данные посоветуйте грамотный код

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Если у тебя неплохо с английским языком, могу посоветовать [уроки на youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DpbUqJcch0Y). Обучают, как писать движок на шаблоне проектирования [MVC](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-View-Controller). Пишут на OOP. Буквально за 20 минут объясняют как писать.
2. По поводу шаблонизатора, самый простой, как по мне, это - [twig](http://x-twig.ru/).

Можешь почитать курсы от [ruseller](https://ruseller.com/lessons.php?id=1145). Специально для начинающих.